# DBT Duplication Check Ignores Schemas

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, architecture, dbt

During `dbt compile`, there is a model duplication check to be sure models aren’t stepping on top of each other.  This check is causing me problems.

**Our Architecture**

Our system delineates the stages of processing into different schemas, and we're wanting begin using dbt. So, say we’re importing a raw dataset we’re calling `jaffles`, we’ll have a `raw.jaffles` table, a `clean.jaffles` table, and so on. Note `raw` and `clean` in this examples are different schemas.

**The Problem**

This breaks the duplication check. No matter how I [customize the schema names](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas#how-does-dbt-generate-a-models-schema-name), or how I [call ref](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref#advanced-ref-usage), the duplication check happens before touching any of that, notices we have two models named “jaffles”, ignores that they wouldn’t actually collide from being in different schemas, and throws an error.

**Possible Solutions**

- Ideally, I'd customize how it solves for the paths it uses to check duplication to include schema. But I can't find how to customize that part.
- Possibly I could skip this check altogether and do the integrity check myself.  But I couldn't find options to disable this.
- The only solution I'm seeing that could work is to rename each of the views to be unique, and this would be a lot of work polluting an otherwise super-clean naming convention we already have established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/unique-model-names), "*model names need to be unique, even if they are in distinct folders*".

What you could do, though, is to use `custom aliases` (see [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-aliases)), where you can re-use the same table/view name within 2 or more different schemas. In your example, you could have two different models that have a specific schema assigned each:

```
-- models/.../raw_jaffles.sql
{{ config(alias='jaffles', schema='raw') }}
```

```
-- models/.../clean_jaffles.sql
{{ config(alias='jaffles', schema='clean') }}
```

Nevertheless, the file names still need to be different one from the other.